# How to Decode image data (sqlite) to show in HTML

Tags: php, sqlite, blob

I have an image data that stored in sqlite database. the data is something like this:

> €TâM89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000012

how to show the data in html with php?

Comment: You should add more details..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a base64 encoding.

If you have a PHP script that can access the database, use the following PHP snippet:

`echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".$base64_data."' />`

Comment: Paste your data at http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html and see if it produces the image. If it doesn't, it's not encoded properly.

Comment: the data is provide from desktop application program and i don't know what exactly method they used to store on database. i can't trace it too since i don't have it source files. i just have .exe file.any suggestion?